# Count number of instances in column of dataframe, bucketize into grid, and predict probability

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to take a dataframe of NFL games, and predict the probability of winning where for example the home team represents the rows and the away team represents the columns (each numbered 0-9).  I want to iterate through each game in the dataframe and count the number of instances that result in each square so that they are 'bucketized', then do the same thing for the predicted scores so that you can get the probability for all 100 squares.

How would I extract the 'ones' digit from scores in each row and do this counting per square?

Any insight and guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out what you meant. So I see what you are after doing the squares.

To get the 'ones', simply convert the score to a string and get the last characheter. Ie `'35'[-1]` will yield `'5'`, then just need to convert that to an `int`. Then just need to do a `.value_counts()` of each combination. To get a percent, divide by how many games are played.

Since you didn't provide any data, I had to get my own:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


df_list = []
for week in range(1, 19):
    print(week)
    url = f'https://www.espn.com/nfl/schedule/_/week/{week}/year/2021'
    df_list += pd.read_html(url)

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
df[['Away','Home']] = df['result'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df = df[['Away','Home']]
df = df.dropna()


def get_digits(row):
        score = int(re.search('\d+', row)[0][-1])
        return score
    
for col in ['Away','Home']:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: get_digits(x))
    
away_counts = df['Away'].value_counts()
home_counts = df['Home'].value_counts() 

data = {}
for col in range(0,10):
    data[col] = []
    try:
        away_count = away_counts[col]
    except:
        away_count = 0
    for row in range(0,10):
        try:
            home_count = home_counts[row]
        except:
            home_count = 0
        
        data[col].append(round((away_count + home_count)/(len(df)*2),3))


results = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results.to_string())
       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
0  0.160  0.162  0.110  0.149  0.160  0.129  0.140  0.171  0.136  0.121
1  0.116  0.118  0.066  0.105  0.116  0.085  0.096  0.127  0.092  0.077
2  0.094  0.096  0.044  0.083  0.094  0.062  0.074  0.105  0.070  0.055
3  0.132  0.134  0.083  0.121  0.132  0.101  0.112  0.143  0.108  0.094
4  0.121  0.123  0.072  0.110  0.121  0.090  0.101  0.132  0.097  0.083
5  0.085  0.086  0.035  0.074  0.085  0.053  0.064  0.096  0.061  0.046
6  0.118  0.119  0.068  0.107  0.118  0.086  0.097  0.129  0.094  0.079
7  0.142  0.143  0.092  0.131  0.142  0.110  0.121  0.153  0.118  0.103
8  0.086  0.088  0.037  0.075  0.086  0.055  0.066  0.097  0.062  0.048
9  0.108  0.110  0.059  0.097  0.108  0.077  0.088  0.119  0.085  0.070
```

[image]